# how to add javascript to an Asp.net MVC app

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am building an Asp.net MVC app and would like to add a datepicker.

I have this code in my form in the view

```
@Html.LabelFor(b => b.Date)
@Html.EditorFor(b => b.Date, new {id = "news_date"})
```

and I would like to add this javascript to it to enable to datapicker:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#news_date").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
});
```

however when the application is run it shows the above code as text on the page.
How do I get it to recognize it as javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap your code with script tags

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#news_date").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: because it is simple :)

Answer (score 2):

Use script tag

```
@Html.LabelFor(b => b.Date)
@Html.EditorFor(b => b.Date, new {id = "news_date"})
    <script  type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#news_date").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: have to wait 5 more mins first